# Как удалить слово из строки checkbox javascript?

Tags: javascript, строки, checkbox, replace, delete

У меня есть чекбоксы, при клике на каждый в кнопке добавляется слово из чекбокса, но если нажать ещё раз на этот же чекбокс, слово опять добавляется.  Нужно убрать это слово.
Ниже код

https://codepen.io/jekalol/pen/dyNbNpj

```
inputs.forEach(el => {
el.addEventListener("change", () => {
    let text = el.parentElement.textContent;
    let btn = el.closest(".filter-item").querySelector(".filter__btn span");

    if(el.checked) {
        el.classList.add("checkbox-active");
    } else {
        el.classList.remove("checkbox-active");
        btn.innerHTML.replace(text)
    }

    let activeCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox-active');

    if(activeCheckboxes.length > 0) {
        btn.innerHTML += text;
    }  else {
        btn.innerHTML = 'Квартиру';
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

У тебя стоит реакция на событие `change`  но помимо этого нужно еще проверить на что поменялся свойство `.checked`

Если он `true` добавляй текс, если `false` не добавляй или удаляй.

```
...
if(activeCheckboxes.checked) {
    //добавить тест
}  else {
    // убрать текст или ничего не делать 
}
```

Comment: а как удалить текст? А точнее строку которую добавили когда я нажал на чекбокс? в этом суть вопроса, когда чекбокс не нажат, его строку удалить из кнопки

Comment: @Shiyan7 `btn.innerHTML.replace(text,'')`